# How to follow-through on HTTP 303 status code when using HttpClient in Java 11 and later?

Tags: java, http-redirect, java-http-client

When using the [`java.net.http.HttpClient`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html) classes in Java 11 and later, how does one tell the client to follow through an [HTTP 303](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303) to get to the redirected page?

Here is an example. [Wikipedia provides a REST URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/#/Page%20content/get_page_random__format_) for getting the summary of a random page of their content. That URL redirects to the URL of the randomly-chosen page. When running this code, I see the `303` when calling `HttpResponse#toString`. But I do not know how to tell the client class to follow along to the new URL.

```java
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
HttpRequest request =
        HttpRequest
                .newBuilder()
                .uri( URI.create( "https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/random/summary" ) )
                .build();
try
{
    HttpResponse < String > response = client.send( request , HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString() );
    System.out.println( "response = " + response );   // ⬅️ We can see the `303` status code.
    String body = response.body();
    System.out.println( "body = " + body );
}
catch ( IOException e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch ( InterruptedException e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When run:

> response = (GET https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/random/summary) 303
>
> body =

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Problem

You're using [`HttpClient#newHttpClient()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html#newHttpClient()). The documentation of that method states:

> Returns a new `HttpClient` with default settings.
>
> Equivalent to `newBuilder().build()`.
>
> The default settings include: the "GET" request method, a preference of HTTP/2, **a redirection policy of `NEVER`** *[emphasis added]*, the default proxy selector, and the default SSL context.

As emphasized, you are creating an `HttpClient` with a redirection policy of `NEVER`.

---

## Solution

There are at least two solutions to your problem.

### Automatically Follow Redirects

If you want to *automatically* follow redirects then you need to use [`HttpClient#newBuilder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html#newBuilder()) (instead of `#newHttpClient()`) which allows you to configure the to-be-built client. Specifically, you need to call [`HttpClient.Builder#followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.Builder.html#followRedirects(java.net.http.HttpClient.Redirect)) with an appropriate redirect policy before building the client. For example:

```java
HttpClient client = 
    HttpClient.newBuilder()
        .followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.NORMAL) // follow redirects
        .build();
```

The different redirect policies are specified by the [`HttpClient.Redirect`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.Redirect.html) enum:

> Defines the automatic redirection policy.
>
> The automatic redirection policy is checked whenever a `3XX` response code is received. If redirection does not happen automatically, then the response, containing the `3XX` response code, is returned, where it can be handled manually.

There are three constants: `ALWAYS`, `NEVER`, and `NORMAL`. The meaning of the first two is obvious from their names. The last one, `NORMAL`, behaves just like `ALWAYS` except it won't redirect from `https` URLs to `http` URLs.

### Manually Follow Redirects

As noted in the documentation of `HttpClient.Redirect` you could instead manually follow a redirect. I'm not well versed in HTTP and how to properly handle all responses so I won't give an example here. But I believe, at a minimum, this requires you:

1. Check the status code of the response.
2. If the code indicates a redirect, grab the new URI from the [response headers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpResponse.html#headers()).
3. If the new URI is relative then resolve it against the request URI.
4. Send a new request.
5. Repeat 1-4 as needed.

Obviously configuring the `HttpClient` to automatically follow redirects is much easier (and less error-prone), but this approach would give you more control.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code where i was calling another api from my REST APi in java.

To note I am using java version **17**. This will solve error code **303**.

```
    @GetMapping(value = "url/api/url")
    private String methodName() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    
    var url = "api/url/"; // remote api url which you want to call
    System.out.println(url);
    var request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().GET().uri(URI.create(url)).setHeader("access-token-key", "accessTokenValue").build();
    
    System.out.println(request);
    var client = HttpClient.newBuilder().followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.NORMAL).build();
    System.out.println(client);

    var response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    System.out.println(response);

    System.out.println(response.body());
    return  response.body();
}
```